# How to print out nicely formatted tables from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, io, nested-loops

For the sake of practicing how to be more comfortable and fluent in working with dictionaries, I have written a little program that reads the content of a file and adds it to a dictionary as a key: value pair. This is no problem, but when I got curious about how to print the content out again in the same format as the table in the datafile using for-loops, I ran into trouble.

***My question is: How can I print out the content of the dictionary onto the terminal using for-loops?***

***The datafile is:***

```
Name    Age     School
Anne    10      Eiksmarka
Tom     15      Marienlyst
Vidar   18      Persbråten
Ayla    18      Kongshavn
Johanne 17      Wang
Silje   16      Eikeli
Per     19      UiO
Ali     25      NTNU
```

***My code is:***

```
infile = open("table.dat", "r")
data = {}

headers = infile.readline().split()
for i in range(len(headers)):
    data[headers[i]] = []

for line in infile:
    words = line.split()
    for i in range(len(headers)):
        data[headers[i]].append(words[i])
infile.close()
```

**I would like the out print the data back onto the terminal. Ideally, the out print should look something like this**

```
Name    Age     School
Anne    10      Eiksmarka
Tom     15      Marienlyst
Vidar   18      Persbråten
Ayla    18      Kongshavn
Johanne 17      Wang
Silje   16      Eikeli
Per     19      UiO
Ali     25      NTNU
```

If someone can help me with this, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use a library such as `Tabulate`, which you can find [here](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/) an example of an output (You can customize it further)

```
>>> from tabulate import tabulate

>>> table = [["Sun",696000,1989100000],["Earth",6371,5973.6],
...          ["Moon",1737,73.5],["Mars",3390,641.85]]
>>> print(tabulate(table))
-----  ------  -------------
Sun    696000     1.9891e+09
Earth    6371  5973.6
Moon     1737    73.5
Mars     3390   641.85
-----  ------  -------------
```

Otherwise, if you MUST use your own custom for-loop, you can add tabs to fix how it looks as in:

`print(a+"\t")` where \t is the horizental tabulation escape character

**Edit:** An example of how this can be utilized is below:

```
infile = open("table.dat", "r")
data = {}

headers = infile.readline().split()
for i in range(len(headers)):
    data[headers[i]] = []

for line in infile:
    words = line.split()
    for i in range(len(headers)):
        data[headers[i]].append(words[i])
        print(words[i],end= '\t')
    print()
infile.close()
```

Things to note:

1- For each field, we use print(...,end= '\t'), this causes the output to be a tab instead of a new line, we also might consider adding more tabs (e.g. `end='\t\t'`) or spaces, or any other formating such as a seperator character (e.g. `end='\t|\t')

2- After each line, we use print(), this will only print a new line, moving the cursor for the printing downwards.

Comment: Thank you for an interesting solution! I will absolutely keep this in mind, but since I'm a beginner practicing my understanding of the interaction between for-loops and dictionaries, my goal is to do this using some kind of a for-loop :-)

Comment: @fredericoamigo Then I will update my answer with a hopefully useful example using for-loops in a few minutes. Cheers buddy.

Comment: Thanks buddy! I truly appreciate the help!

Comment: @fredericoamigo I have updated the answer, let me know if anything is unclear, Cheers

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me in my learning!  All of your solutions are very helpful! Cheers :-)

Comment: After slightly altering you code, I learned that changing the line ```print(words[i],end= '\t')``` to ```print(f"{words[i]:<10}", end="")``` is a possible improvement for an even nicer out print. (This is nit picking of course :-P )

Comment: Yup, that's fine. There are many ways to improve those code, both from a visual standpoint and a reliability standpoint, as using a constant number of tabs might have an issue if you have too few tabs (then you will not have things lined up), or having too many tabs (Too much free space), but I hope it was helpful enough to get started so you can try out and customise it as needed :)

Answer (score 2):

Take look at [`.ljust`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust), [`.rjust`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rjust) and [`.center`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.center) methods of `str`, consider following simple example

```
d = {"Alpha": 1, "Beta": 10, "Gamma": 100, "ExcessivelyLongName": 1}
for key, value in d.items():
    print(key.ljust(5), str(value).rjust(3))
```

output

```
Alpha   1
Beta   10
Gamma 100
ExcessivelyLongName   1
```

Note that `ljust` does add (by default) space to attain specified width or do nothing if name is longer than that, also as values are integers they need to be first converted to `str` if you want to use one of mentioned methods.

Comment: Thank you so much for providing an alternative solution. It is very helpful. Appreciate it :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/) although it isn't exactly your same styling:

```
import pandas as pd

with open('filename.csv') as f:
    headers, *data = map(str.split, f.readlines())

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(headers, zip(*data)))

print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

---

```
   Name Age     School
   Anne  10  Eiksmarka
    Tom  15 Marienlyst
  Vidar  18 Persbråten
   Ayla  18  Kongshavn
Johanne  17       Wang
  Silje  16     Eikeli
    Per  19        UiO
    Ali  25       NTNU
```

Comment: Thanks! Now that I have gotten better at my "hard coding", it's nice to know that pandas is a good alternative! Cheers!

Comment: Well just fyi, the code I wrote minus the `pd.DataFrame` part makes the dict how you like. Just wrap `g` in `list` and you have your data in `dict` form. much more simple and easy to read than your original approach. Hopefully you're able to make sense of it.

Comment: @fredericoamigo please see my edit.

Comment: Thaks! Works well :-) I've been wanting to learn more about using pandas for a while now, and this is a good opportunity for doing just that.